# Terraform For Each Reference Index In Output

Tags: terraform

I have a module where I am generating several lambdas programmatically using for_each.

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "profile" {
  for_each = local.lambdas

  function_name = each.value.lambda_name
  role          = var.lambda_assume_role_arn
  image_uri     = each.value.ecr_repository_uri
  package_type  = "Image"

  vpc_config {
    security_group_ids = [var.rds_security_group_id]
    subnet_ids         = var.subnet_ids
  }
}
```

Two of these generated lambdas I need to to export in output.tf

```
output "aws_lambda_function_pre_sign_up_arn" {
  value       = aws_lambda_function.profile[9].arn
}

output "aws_lambda_function_post_confirmation_arn" {
  value       = aws_lambda_function.profile[0].arn
}
```

When I apply I get an error:

```
╷
│ Error: Invalid index
│ 
│   on ../modules/services/profile/ouptput.tf line 2, in output "aws_lambda_function_pre_sign_up_arn":
│    2:   value       = aws_lambda_function.profile[9]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ aws_lambda_function.profile is object with 10 attributes
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value. An object only supports looking up attributes by name, not by numeric index.
╵
╷
│ Error: Invalid index
│ 
│   on ../modules/services/profile/ouptput.tf line 7, in output "aws_lambda_function_post_confirmation_arn":
│    7:   value       = aws_lambda_function.profile[0]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ aws_lambda_function.profile is object with 10 attributes
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value. An object only supports looking up attributes by name, not by numeric index.
╵
```

Here is a snippet of what the locals look like. There are 10 entires in all.

```
locals {
  service = "profile"
  lambdas = {
    assign_default_group = {
      lambda_name                  = "${lower(var.company)}-${local.service}-${var.environment}-assign_default_group",
      ecr_repository_name          = "${lower(var.company)}/${local.service}/${var.environment}/lambda/assign_default_group",
      ecr_repository_uri           = "xxx.dkr.ecr.${var.region}.amazonaws.com/${lower(var.company)}/${local.service}/${var.environment}/lambda/assign_default_group:latest"
      lambda_environment_variables = {
        RDS_STORAGE_URL      = var.storage_url
        COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID = jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.profile.secret_string)["cognito_user_pool_id"]
      }
    },
    create_account = {
      lambda_name                  = "${lower(var.company)}-${local.service}-${var.environment}-create_account",
      ecr_repository_name          = "${lower(var.company)}/${local.service}/${var.environment}/lambda/create_account",
      ecr_repository_uri           = "xxx.dkr.ecr.${var.region}.amazonaws.com/${lower(var.company)}/${local.service}/${var.environment}/lambda/create_account:latest"
      lambda_environment_variables = {
        RDS_STORAGE_URL = var.storage_url
      }
    },
...
```

Comment: There are no idexes when using `for_each`, only keys. Since you didn't post the value of the local variable `lambdas` it's hard to tell which values you want for outputs

Comment: @MarkoE I added snippet of what locals look like.

Comment: Great, so you want all ten of them or only the first and the last?

Comment: @MarkoE in this scenario just the first and last but in general I would like to be able to reference one or more using an index; assuming that is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, using indexes with resources created with `for_each` meta-argument is not possible [1]. If using indexes is required then `count` meta-argument should be used [2]. If you decide to proceed with using `for_each`, you could fetch the desired outputs in the following way:

```
output "aws_lambda_function_pre_sign_up_arn" {
  value       = aws_lambda_function.profile["first_key"].arn
}

output "aws_lambda_function_post_confirmation_arn" {
  value       = aws_lambda_function.profile["last_key"].arn
}
```

Since I do not know which key is first (I'm guessing `assign_default_group`) and which is the last (for the sake of example, let's go with `create_account`), the above becomes:

```
output "aws_lambda_function_pre_sign_up_arn" {
  value       = aws_lambda_function.profile["assign_default_group"].arn
}

output "aws_lambda_function_post_confirmation_arn" {
  value       = aws_lambda_function.profile["create_account"].arn
}
```

But based on the output name, there is probably a key named `post_confirmation` and a key named `pre_sign_up`, so you can use that as the key values.

If you need to fetch a certain attribute for a number of Lambda functions (whether it is ARN or something else), you could do the following:

```
output "lambda_arns" {
  value = {
    for k, v in aws_lambda_function.profile : k => v.arn
  }
}
```

This will return a map of key/value pairs, where key will again be a key from the local variable `lambdas` and the value will be the Lambda function ARN.

Alternatively, you could use the `values` built-in function [3] with the `splat` expression [4] to derive only values and the return result will be a list (where you could reference elements by index value):

```
output "lambda_arns" {
  value = values(aws_lambda_function.profile)[*].arn
}
```

There could be more different ways to get the values but it depends on the type of output you would like to get.

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each#referring-to-instances

[2] https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/count#referring-to-instances

[3] https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/values

[4] https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/splat